Wall parallel with ceiling/floor joists, but supports screwed into joist
Just bought a house and there are two walls that run parallel with the floor joists for the second level. Neither wall is directly under the joist. But each wall does have its framing nailed into the side of the joist. Does that mean these walls are loadbearing?

Parallel is usually not load bearing(maybe 1 in 100,000).  Being attached to the side makes it even less load bearing.  Nails/screws do not hold that much weight.  Is there another wall going the other way/across the joists?  That is load bearing.  Many questions on here about finding load bearing walls.  Use the search box on top.

Second story walls would have to somehow transfer the building load to a first story wall or column in order to be load-bearing. Just FYI https://www.homedepot.com/c/ab/how-to-tell-if-a-wall-is-load-bearing/9ba683603be9fa5395fab90151d85162

What makes the wall “load bearing” is what it carries above it.  That said, it’s likely the wall is not, given the nature of the connection you’ve described. If it bore any significant load, it seems likely you’d see evidence of drywall damage or twisting in the studs.  That said, non-load-bearing walls can become load bearing over time under the right / wrong circumstances.
Ultimately, your description lacks a lot of detail. The goal is to determine what framing might be carried by these walls that isn’t carried some other way. Highly recommend you talk to a contractor or a knowledgeable acquaintance if you can’t provide more detail.

Answers should not ask questions of the OP, that belongs in comments.  However +1 for talking to a contractor.
